# Using withRouter and connect, how does one assert in enzyme that history.push was called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, enzyme

I am using withRouter and connect in a stateless React component. I have a button in the component that calls a method in props which is provided by mapDispatchToProps.

I am trying to write a test that asserts that pressing the button calls history.push().

So far, I have not been able to find a way to do it. Some places say that passing in a mock history object like this

```
const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
...
<MyComponent history={mockHistory}/>
```

will do it, but that does not work. I think the call to withRouter overwrites it. I also tried placing that in Provider and Router. None work.

I have also tried mocking mapDispatchToProps, or otherwise setting a spy on setHistory. That all seems impossible.

I have also tried spying on the MyComponent function to get the props passed into it - also impossible.

wrapper.setProps() - also does not work.

I have these files.

my.component.container.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const {setHistory, id} = props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Button id="history_button" onClick={() => {
                setHistory(id)
            }}>View</Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};

export default MyComponent;
```

my.component.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import MyComponentContainer from './my.component.container';

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const id = state?.data?.id || null;
    return {id};
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        setHistory: (id) => {
            const {history} = ownProps;
            history.push(`/path/${id}`);
        },
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentContainer));
```

my.component.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import MyComponent from './my.component';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

    afterEach(function() {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    const getNode = (wrapper, search) => {
        return wrapper.find(search).hostNodes();
    };

    it('history buttons calls history.push()', () => {
        const initialState = {data: {id: 'id-1'}};
        const mockStore = configureStore();
        const store = mockStore(initialState);
        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Router><MyComponent/></Router></Provider>);
        const button = getNode(wrapper, '#history_button');
        button.simulate('click');
        // to do - assert that history.push was called with '/path/id-1'
    });
});
```

And I'll throw this out as a solution that I do not like much. I am looking to spy on the history object in general.

```
expect(window.history.length).toEqual(1);
expect(window.location.href).toEqual('http://localhost/');

button.simulate('click');

expect(window.history.length).toEqual(2);
expect(window.location.href).toEqual('http://localhost/path/id-1');
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried passing history to the `Router` component as you did:

```
<Router history={historyMock}>
```

When I ran the test, it said:

```
  console.warn node_modules/tiny-warning/dist/tiny-warning.cjs.js:13
    Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.
```

Once I changed the import as it suggested, passing `Router` the mock history object worked.

my.component.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
// import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; // Warning: <BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import MyComponent from './my.component';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

    afterEach(function() {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    const getNode = (wrapper, search) => {
        return wrapper.find(search).hostNodes();
    };

    it('history buttons calls history.push()', () => {
        const initialState = {data: {id: 'id-1'}};
        const mockStore = configureStore();
        const store = mockStore(initialState);
        const historyMock = {
            listen: () => {},
            location: {
                pathname: 'fake-path-name',
            },
            push: jest.fn(),
        };
        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Router history={historyMock}><MyComponent history={'this is ignored and useless'}/></Router></Provider>);
        const button = getNode(wrapper, '#history_button');

        button.simulate('click');

        expect(historyMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(historyMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path/id-1');
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't have the same issue, but the note to use plain `Router` instead of `MemoryRouter` or `BrowserRouter` was the key for me. Thanks!